# Merging a dataframe with column names from an empty dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two `df`s (`df`, `df2`).
Although `df` doesn't have every column name, but `df2` does.

`df2`, however, is empty:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
    ID = 1:5,
    DOG = replicate(5, rbinom(1, 1, 0.5)), 
    CAT = replicate(5, rbinom(1, 1, 0.5)),
    FISH = replicate(5, rbinom(1, 1, 0.5)))

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(, nrow=0, ncol=7))
names(df2) <- c("DOG", "CAT", "FISH", "CRANE", "PIG", "SHARK", "DEER")
```

I want to "combine" the two dataframes without matching anything together. I basically just want `df` to contain all the columns from `df2`, but `NA`-ed.

Desired Output:

```
ID DOG CAT FISH CRANE PIG SHARK DEER
1   0   1    0    NA  NA    NA   NA
2   0   1    0    NA  NA    NA   NA
3   1   1    1    NA  NA    NA   NA  
4   1   1    0    NA  NA    NA   NA
5   0   0    1    NA  NA    NA   NA
```

Comment: try `bind_rows(df2, df)`

Comment: Did you actually test `dplyr::full_join`? Because I just did and it gives me the output you say you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df2, df)
#  DOG CAT FISH CRANE PIG SHARK DEER
#1   0   1    0    NA  NA    NA   NA
#2   0   1    0    NA  NA    NA   NA
#3   1   1    1    NA  NA    NA   NA
#4   1   1    0    NA  NA    NA   NA
#5   0   0    1    NA  NA    NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Base package:

```
merge(df, df2, all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
  DOG CAT FISH ID CRANE PIG SHARK DEER
1   0   1    0  1    NA  NA    NA   NA
2   0   1    0  2    NA  NA    NA   NA
3   1   1    1  3    NA  NA    NA   NA
4   1   1    0  4    NA  NA    NA   NA
5   0   0    1  5    NA  NA    NA   NA
```

Preserving the order of the columns:

```
merge(df, df2, all =TRUE, sort = FALSE)[, union(names(df), names(df2))]
```

Output:

```
  ID DOG CAT FISH CRANE PIG SHARK DEER
1  1   0   1    0    NA  NA    NA   NA
2  2   0   1    0    NA  NA    NA   NA
3  3   1   1    1    NA  NA    NA   NA
4  4   1   1    0    NA  NA    NA   NA
5  5   0   0    1    NA  NA    NA   NA
```

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT * FROM df
      LEFT JOIN df2
      USING(DOG, CAT, FISH)")
```

Output:

```
  ID DOG CAT FISH CRANE PIG SHARK DEER
1  1   0   1    0    NA  NA    NA   NA
2  2   0   1    0    NA  NA    NA   NA
3  3   1   1    1    NA  NA    NA   NA
4  4   1   1    0    NA  NA    NA   NA
5  5   0   0    1    NA  NA    NA   NA
```